# Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function. If $\int_0^1 f\, dx =0$ then $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function. If $\int_0^1 f\, dx =0$ then $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

I'm thinking this involves the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus when trying to prove it.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1531249/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1219414/42969

Answer (score 1):

**Proof:**

Suppose $f(x)\not=0\;\;\forall x\in[0,1]$ then $\exists \;x_0 $ such that $f(x_0)>0$.

Let $a=f(x_0)$ and choose $\epsilon=a/2$.

Now note that $f$ is continuoys at $x_0$, so for $\epsilon=a/2$ $\exists \;\delta>0$ such that $f(x)\in(\frac{a}{2},\frac{3a}{2})$ for $x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$.

Using some properties of Riemann Integrals we have,

$$\int_0^{1}f(x)dx\ge\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}f(x)dx\ge\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta}\frac{a}{2}dx=a\delta>0$$

A contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Suppose $f(x_0)=c > 0$ somewhere.  By continuity assumption, you can find a little $\delta$ neighborhood around $x_0$ in which $f$ is strictly positive the entire time.  You can then split the integral $\int_0^1 f\, dx$ into a few pieces.  In the neighborhood around $x_0$ the integral is bounded below by a positive quantity, and in the other two intervals it is bounded below by $0$, since $f$ is a nonnegative function by assumption.